# View only one data related to model in rails through console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model User. I want to check all the phone number related to user.
I have list all the data related to user as

```
User.all
```

I just want phone number attribute to display i.e all the phone number of user.
And lastly I want to check this query through console and implement in the project.

Comment: Do you want to see a list of all users but only return phone_number attribute or the phone number of a specific user? Is phone number an attribute or a model association?

Comment: Do you mean like `User.pluck(:phone_number)`?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes I exactly want that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **User.pluck(:phone_number)** to fetch phone numbers of all the users and also check the query from rails console.